# Can’t convert np.ndarray of type numpy.bool_

Tags: pytorch

I am wondering why I am getting this error when I used :

```
Y_train_class = torch.tensor(Y_train_class.values)
```

> TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.bool_. The only supported types are: double, float, float16, int64, int32, and uint8.

I have tried to convert my data to float but seems failed

```
X_train = pd.read_csv('c:/Data/x_train_set_yu.csv', header= None)
Y_train = pd.read_csv('c:/Data/y_train_set_yu.1.csv', header= None)

Y_train_class = (Y_train >= 550)
print (Y_train_class)
X_test = pd.read_csv('c:/Data/X_test.csv',header= None)

X_train = torch.tensor(X_train.values)

Y_train.astype(np.float32)
Y_train_class.astype(np.float32)

Y_train_class = torch.tensor(Y_train_class.values)
```

> TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.bool_. The only supported types are: double, float, float16, int64, int32, and uint8.

Comment: Can you please post some of the entries of y_train_set_yu.1.csv file to better understand the problem?. I think your are getting error because of float('True')/float('False'). Boolean value can't be parsed as a float number.

Answer (score 1):

I got this type of error when my `Y_train` had a string value instead of integers. After replacing strings with integers my error got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You're generally following the correct approach, except numpy `astype` is not in-place. So instead of

```
Y_train_class.astype(np.float32)
```

you need to have

```
Y_train_class = Y_train_class.astype(np.float32)
```

(currently your original `Y_train_class.astype(np.float32)` could effectively not be executed).

If your goal is to train with loss functions such as [`nn.BinaryCrossEntropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss), your approach of casting to float is correct, as they expect the 0/1 classes to be `float32` anyway. In the general case, PyTorch uses `uint8` tensors in place of boolean tensors, so to get a functional equivalent of your original numpy tensor, you should use `torch.from_numpy(Y_train_class.astype(np.uint8))` - it then correctly supports masking operations as in numpy, example below

```
import torch
import numpy as np

test_vals = np.array([1, 3, 3])
array = np.array([True, True, False], dtype=np.bool)
print(test_vals[array])

test_vals = torch.from_numpy(test_vals)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(array.astype(np.uint8))
print(test_vals[tensor])
```

Finally, as far as I know, boolean tensors are coming to PyTorch in future versions.